# Unix command & regex to remove XML tag from Corpus

Tags: regex, unix, grep, tokenize

I used the text a Corpus and I wrote the following Unix commands and regex.

I want to extract text without XML ***for only the English segments*** and put in a file called “file.txt”.

The following code removes only the `<seg>`,but it keeps the ending XML tag which is `</seg>` . Look at the input and the output to understand my problem.

```
cat uncorpora_plain.txt |grep -a1 '<tuv xml:lang="EN">' |grep '<seg>' |perl -pe 's/\<seg>\b/''/'
```

Part of the text before extracting:

```
  <tuv xml:lang="EN">
    <seg>Adopted at the 81st plenary meeting, on 4 December 2000, on 
   the recommendation of the Committee (A/55/602/Add.2 and Corr.1, 
   para. 94), by a recorded vote of 106 to 1, with 67 abstentions, as 
   follows:</seg>
```

The Output after run the Unix command:

```
    Adopted at the 81st plenary meeting, on 4 December 2000, on the 
 recommendation of the Committee (A/55/602/Add.2 and Corr.1, para. 94), 
 by a recorded vote of 106 to 1, with 67 abstentions, as follows:</seg>
```

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want: `sed 's/<tuv xml:lang="EN">\|<seg>\|<\/seg>//g' file.xml`

Comment: I should use this command (grep -a1)

Comment: Why should you use that command, if another command achieves the result you're looking for with less effort and more clarity?

Comment: I've tried the code and it doesn't work with me, and I would like to understand more grep -a1 and how can I apply it to the corpus. Thank you

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `-a` option tells grep to treat all files as ASCII text. What do YOU think it should be doing?  Why not just `sed 's:</*[^>]*>::g'` ?  Or `awk '{gsub(/<\/?[^>]+>/,"")}1'` ?  Or `pcregrep -o "(?<=<seg>)[^<]+|^[^<>]+$|[^<]+(?=</seg>)"`? Or better yet, use something that *actually parses XML*. Because [you can't parse XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1072112).

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' file.xml
```

This should work

Comment: It works and removes all the tags but keeps all text from  other languages.

Comment: @BeautifulMind, What other languages? This solution appears to produce exactly what your question said you were looking for, given the sample data you included. There are no open tags or close tags in its output. It gets my upvote.

Comment: The corpus contains 6 languages. I want to remove all the XML tags & other languages as well and Keep only English segments.

Comment: @BeautifulMind it's always trivial to select the text you want from a file and far harder to **not** select the text you **don't** want so if your real input flle contains text you do not want selected then obviously the sample you provide in your question to demonstrate your problem and for us to test a potential solution against must likewise contain representative samples of that unwanted text, not just the wanted text.

Answer (score 1):

I would repeat the hackneyed rule: ***don't parse xml/html with awk/sed/grep*** - use appropriate parsers.

[**xmlstarlet**](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) is one of them.

Valid XML sample:

```
<root>
 <tuv xml:lang="EN">
    <seg>Adopted at the 81st plenary meeting, on 4 December 2000, on 
   the recommendation of the Committee (A/55/602/Add.2 and Corr.1, 
   para. 94), by a recorded vote of 106 to 1, with 67 abstentions, as 
   follows:</seg>
</tuv>
 <tuv xml:lang="UA">
    <seg>УкраÏна - унікальна країна,
     багата талановитими людьми ...</seg>
</tuv>
</root>
```

---

The command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//tuv[@xml:lang='EN']//seg" -n input.xml > uncorpus.eng.txt
```

---

`uncorpus.eng.txt` contents:

```
Adopted at the 81st plenary meeting, on 4 December 2000, on 
   the recommendation of the Committee (A/55/602/Add.2 and Corr.1, 
   para. 94), by a recorded vote of 106 to 1, with 67 abstentions, as 
   follows:
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you're asking for (using GNU awk for multi-char RS):

```
awk -v RS='</seg>' 'sub(/.*<tuv\s+xml:lang="EN">\s*<seg>/,"")'
```

but without testable sample input/output it's a guess. Here it is running against the input @RomanPerekhrest made up FWIW:

```
$ cat file
<root>
 <tuv xml:lang="EN">
    <seg>Adopted at the 81st plenary meeting, on 4 December 2000, on
   the recommendation of the Committee (A/55/602/Add.2 and Corr.1,
   para. 94), by a recorded vote of 106 to 1, with 67 abstentions, as
   follows:</seg>
</tuv>
 <tuv xml:lang="UA">
    <seg>УкраÏна - унікальна країна,
     багата талановитими людьми ...</seg>
</tuv>
</root>

$ awk -v RS='</seg>' 'sub(/.*<tuv\s+xml:lang="EN">\s*<seg>/,"")' file
Adopted at the 81st plenary meeting, on 4 December 2000, on
   the recommendation of the Committee (A/55/602/Add.2 and Corr.1,
   para. 94), by a recorded vote of 106 to 1, with 67 abstentions, as
   follows:
```

and if you wanted to get rid of the blank space at the start of each line:

```
$ awk -v RS='</seg>' 'sub(/.*<tuv\s+xml:lang="EN">\s*<seg>/,""){ gsub(/\n[[:blank:]]*/,"\n"); print}' file
Adopted at the 81st plenary meeting, on 4 December 2000, on
the recommendation of the Committee (A/55/602/Add.2 and Corr.1,
para. 94), by a recorded vote of 106 to 1, with 67 abstentions, as
follows:
```